# Put String[] in a String[][]?

Tags: java, arrays, string

Ok, soo what I'm trying to do, I have an oject with a attribut which looks like `String[][]`, and I want to fill this one by calling a function and fill this `String[][]`, one by one.
So here is what I tried but I get an error telling me :

"The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to String"
When  I try to do

`Produit[NbrProduit][0] = Produit[0];`

My code :

```
public String[][] Produit = new String[MAX_Produit][2];

public void GetInfo1(String Client, String[] Produit,int NbrProduit){
    Produit[NbrProduit][0] = Produit[0];
    Produit[NbrProduit][1] = Produit[1];
    Produit[NbrProduit][2] = Produit[2];
```

I don't understand why I get this because I'm filling a String field with an another String, right ? no ?

Sorry for my english.

Comment: Just a recommendation: Try to follow Java naming conventions. Use `'mixedCase'` for methods/variables and use `'CamelCase'` for classes/interfaces.

Comment: Produit[0] returns a String[] you are trying to put it into String[][]

Comment: You declare Produit as an 2D array but on the bottom you using it as single array?

Comment: Produit[NbrProduit][0] is a String. Produit[0] is a String[].

Comment: @Christian : I will, but is this the official : http://java.about.com/od/javasyntax/a/nameconventions.htm ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your parameter name (a 1D array) is the same as your instance variable name (a 2D array), so you're actually referring to your parameter only. Either use a different name (recommended), or use `this.Produit` when referring to your 2D array.

i.e.

```
public void GetInfo1(String Client, String[] produitParam,int NbrProduit){
    Produit[NbrProduit][0] = produitParam[0];
    Produit[NbrProduit][1] = produitParam[1];
    Produit[NbrProduit][2] = produitParam[2];
```

Comment: :o You are right, it was my mistake, I use 2 times the same name -_- Ok now it works fine , Thanks ^^

Answer (score 0):

Produit is a two dimensional String array, which means each of its element will be a string array. So you need to assign the element with the array of String and not just one String. Try this if it makes sense for your logic:

```
this.Produit[NbrProduit][0] = Produi;
```